# SwiftUI: Bound @State Variable Not Updated When Showing Sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, state, swiftui-state

I am experiencing an issue with SwiftUI where a bound @State variable (displayString) does not seem to get updated in time when a sheet is presented. The code provided consists of a parent view (SimpleParentView) and a child view (SimpleChildView). The parent view presents a sheet when showSheet is set to true, and the sheet displays the displayString value.

The problem arises when either "Button 1" or "Button 2" in the SimpleChildView is pressed for the first time. When pressed, it's intended to update displayString and then present the sheet by setting showSheet to true. However, when the sheet is presented on the first button press, it still displays "Initial String," indicating that the displayString hasn't been updated in time for the presentation of the sheet.

Interestingly, if the user dismisses the sheet and then presses the opposite button or the same button again, the sheet displays the updated displayString correctly, and any subsequent button presses also work as intended.

I've tried using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter to delay the setting of showSheet to true, hoping this would allow enough time for displayString to get updated, but this approach doesn't seem to make any difference.

I also tired "priming" the assignment by assigning a throw-away value first, in hopes that this would take care of that initial mysterious miss-assignement, but that doesn't work either.

Why is this happening?

```
import Foundation

import SwiftUI

struct SimpleParentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var displayString = "Initial String"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SimpleChildView(showSheet: $showSheet, displayString: $displayString)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            VStack {
                Text(displayString)
                Button("Close") {
                    showSheet = false
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleChildView: View {
    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    @Binding var displayString: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // This "priming the assignment" hack makes no difference
            // displayString = ""
            displayString = "Updated String 1"
            showSheet = true
            // This delayed assignment hack makes no difference
            /*
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                showSheet = true
            }*/
        }) {
            Text("Button 1 (show sheet in parent)")
        }
        Button(action: {
            displayString = "Updated String 2"
            showSheet = true
        }) {
            Text("Button 2 (show sheet in parent)")
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleParentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SimpleParentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `.sheet(item: ...)` instead. There are many examples on SO and the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem intentional and might be a bug in SwiftUI.

It appears that SwiftUI made an initial version of the sheet, and showed that when `showSheet` becomes true, failing to notice that the sheet's content uses `displayString` and hence should be redrawn. `ContentView.body` is only evaluated once, until you press a different button.

`ContentView`'s `body` (not counting the sheet) doesn't use `displayString` - only bindings of it.  That might have caused SwiftUI to think it doesn't need to be updated. This is only speculation though.

In any case, if you make `ContentView` have the slightest dependency on `displayString`, this behaviour does not happen. It could be a hidden `Text`:

```
Text(displayString).hidden()
```

or even just an `onChange` modifier:

```
VStack {
    ...
}
.onChange(of: displayString) { _ in }
```

And this is my favourite - even just discarding `displayString` with `let _ =` works:

```
VStack {
    let _ = displayString
    SimpleChildView(showSheet: $showSheet, displayString: $displayString)
        .sheet(...) { ... }
}
```

As a final note, if `displayString` can be nil when the sheet is not showing, you can use [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) instead. This way `SimpleChildView` just needs one binding.

Answer (score 2):

Use a closure to capture the state var `displayString`, such as:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { [displayString] in  // <--- here
        VStack {
            Text(displayString)
            Button("Close") {
                showSheet = false
            }
            .padding()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleParentView`'s `body` isn't called when `displayString` is set because it wasn't previously read.

SwiftUI only calls `body` when a `@State` is `set` if its `get` was used. This is SwiftUI's dependency tracking feature (which is not documented).

working dog's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77169574/259521) is one way to `get` the `displayString` but if you get it anywhere else in `body` it will achieve the same effect. I suppose it is a bug that the dependency tracking does not reach into a sheet's closure, it does however work for other kinds of View closures. It's probably because the sheet closure is more of an action rather than a view builder.