# SwiftUI sheets sometimes seem to use stale @State values when they are first rendered - How to use actual State?

Tags: swiftui

SwiftUI sheets sometimes seem to use stale @State values when they are first rendered. Is there a way around this without using a read-only capture, so that the state remains writable? I need a solution that works with multiple State variables, and does not use a separate View struct for the .sheet view because the sheet view needs to be able to call non-static member functions of the ContentView.

In the example below when the `sheet` opens it sees `@State value` as nil and crashes, even though `value` was set before `showSheet`. The sheet content already directly uses `value`, so the typical `let _ = value` and `.onChange(of: value) { _ in }` tricks don't work/help.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var value : Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            openSheet()
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                Text("\(value!)") // crashes
            }
        )
    }
    
    func openSheet() {
        value = Date()
        showSheet = true
    }
}
```

Using a capture does not achieve my goal, as in this example, because the capture is read-only, and is no longer `State`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var value : Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            openSheet()
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                [value] in // read-only
                Text("\(value!)")
            }
        )
    }
    
    func openSheet() {
        value = Date()
        showSheet = true
    }
}
```

The solution suggested by @Spiritofthecore using `.mappedToBool()` works but only if there is only 2 variables to combine - in my actual app the sheet view uses multiple state values shared with the ContentView.

This example, based on @malhal's suggestion, doesn't seem to work - the first render of the sheet uses stale values:

```
struct Popup {
    var show = false
    var toDate = Date()
    var intValue = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popup = Popup()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            popup.intValue = 1
            popup.toDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: popup.toDate)!
            popup.show = true
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $popup.show) {
            VStack {
                Text("\(popup.toDate) - \(popup.intValue)")
                
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: Binding(
                        get: {
                            print("get \(popup.toDate)")
                            return popup.toDate
                        },
                        set: {newDate,_ in
                            popup.toDate = newDate
                            print("really set \(popup.toDate) to \(newDate)")
                        }),
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using the `.sheet(item:` api, similar to @vadian's solution but changes that the sheet makes to the item don't cause the sheet to rerender:

```
struct Popup : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    @State var toDate = Date()
    @State var intValue = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var popup : Popup?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            popup = Popup(
                toDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!,
                intValue: 1)
        }
        .sheet(item: $popup) { popup in
            VStack {
                Text("\(popup.toDate) - \(popup.intValue)")
                
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: Binding(
                        get: {
                            print("get \(popup.toDate)")
                            return popup.toDate
                        },
                        set: {value,_ in
                            popup.toDate = value
                            popup.intValue += 1
                            print("really set \(popup.toDate) to \(value)")
                        }),
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77169389/5133585

Comment: @sweeper Thank you, but the tricks in those answers don't work in this case. Capturing the value makes it read only. And the .sheet content directly uses `value`, so the `let _ = value` and `.onChange(of: value) { _ in }` don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-optional state struct to combine related vars and make sure you call the state getter somewhere in body, e.g. the sheet closure's capture list, e.g.

```
struct SheetData {
    var showSheet: Bool = false

    var value: Date?

    mutating func show(value: Date) {
       self.value = value
       self.showSheet = true
    }
}
...
@State var sheetData = SheetData()
...
.sheet(isPresented: $sheetData.showSheet) { [sheetData] in // only need this capture list if didn't already read sheetData somewhere else in body.
     SheetView(sheetData: $sheetData)  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to be able to modify SheetData.value in the sheet view (which is why i cant use a capture). In your solution does SheetData.value need to be a State? I tried with State which didn’t seem to work, and also with Binding which only works sometimes- sometimes changes to the binding are somehow reverted by swiftui.

Comment: sheetData is not optional which will prevent that

Comment: Thank you, but making the sheetData not optional doesn't seem to work. I added a fully reproducible example to my question. Please help me understand if my example is wrong.

Comment: you are missing a call to the state getter inside body. Try this: `.sheet(isPresented: $popup.show) { [popup] in`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach using a separate `View` and a `Binding` for the sheet.

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var value : Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            openSheet()
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
                SheetView(value: $value)  // <--- here
            }
        )
    }
    
    func openSheet() {
        value = Date()
        showSheet = true
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {  // <--- here
    @Binding var value: Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value!)")
        Button("Change value") {  // <--- for testing
            value = Date()
        }
        .onChange(of: value) { 
            print("---> value: \(value)")  // <--- for testing
        }
    }
}
```

Using MacOS 14.4 and Xcode 15.3, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst.

Comment: Thank you, that is a working solution but I can't use it in my real app, because my sheet needs to call non static methods defined in ContentView, and I dont think that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your sheet use stale @State values when they are first rendered because sheet(isPresented:) don't listen the date value being changed.
In this use case, you can convert the Optional @State value to Bool, like this gist: https://gist.github.com/JosephDuffy/f6291ad150e8aedf4515c29fdf5ab7e3

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value : Date?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            openSheet()
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$value.mappedToBool()) {
                Text("\(value!)") // crashes
            }
        )
    }
    
    func openSheet() {
        value = Date()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great but it only works if there is a single data variable that can be used as isPresented

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is make `Date` conform to `Identifiable`

```
extension Date: Identifiable {
    public var id : String { formatted( 
        .iso8601 // ISO8601 string with fractional seconds
            .year().month().day()
            .timeZone(separator: .omitted)
            .time(includingFractionalSeconds: true)
            .timeSeparator(.colon)
    )}
}
```

and use the `.sheet(item:…)` API

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
        @State private var value : Date?
        
        var body: some View {
            Button("Open Sheet") {
                openSheet()
            }
            .overlay(
                EmptyView()
                    .sheet(item: $value) { value in
                    Text(value.id)
                }
            )
        }
        
        func openSheet() {
            value = Date()
        }
}
```

Edit: The code applied to your example, the goal is to modify `self.popup`

```
struct Popup : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var toDate = Date() // @State property wrappers make only sense in SwiftUI views
    var intValue = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var popup : Popup?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open Sheet") {
            popup = Popup(
                toDate: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!,
                intValue: 1)
        }
        .sheet(item: $popup) { popup in
            VStack {
                Text("\(popup.toDate) - \(popup.intValue)")
                
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: Binding(
                        get: {
                            print("get \(popup.toDate)")
                            return popup.toDate
                        },
                        set: {value,_ in
                            self.popup?.toDate = value
                            self.popup?.intValue += 1
                            print("really set \(popup.toDate) to \(value)")
                        }),
                    displayedComponents: .date
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but changes that the sheet makes to the item don't cause the sheet to rerender. I added a full example of that to the question. Please let me know if I misunderstood.